# Selenium python conditional

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying selenium in python and this is my code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('url')
x = 0
enterprises = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content']//div[@class='li']//div[1]")
for enterprise in enterprises:
   if x != 0
```

And when i execute my code i'm getting this error.

> File "main.py", line 11
>       if x != 0
>               ^

Why i'm getting this error? is not correct the conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it missing the colon `:` at the end.

```
if x != 0:
  ...
```